# What's the difference between individual account SSH keys and team SSH keys in Bitbucket settings

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, bitbucket.org

Our team has two entities on Bitbucket, the Freelensia.com "individual" account and the Freelensors "team".
[image: individual photo]
[image: team photo]

Each of them has an "SSH keys" section, for example the individual account SSH keys are below:

[image: SSH keys for individual account]

For the Freelensors team, we currently have no SSH keys.

We understand that the individual SSH keys enable that particular user to push codes to bitbucket. Meaning that whenever Bitbucket sees this key coming in, it will automatically associate it with the individual and validate his permissions.

But how do SSH keys for teams work? Especially when we have multiple groups within a team with different access rights. Does Bitbucket automatically assume that whoever is using a key inside team SSH keys is an administrator?

We looked up The Teams page of Bitbucket but there is no mention how SSH keys work. https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/teams-321853005.html

Answer (score 0):

The ssh key is not used only for authorizing access to that account, but also to uniquely identify the connecting user, which is a reason why it [can not have the key assigned to multiple users](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bbkb/someone-has-already-registered-that-ssh-key-338365482.html).

But the keys do not need to be used only for publishing code, but might be used also for reading the code by some services (CI/CD) if the code is in private repository.

In that case, it is useful to have some keys with read-only access given to the team that can access all the projects under the team

Comment: How do assign some keys read-only access in the team's SSH keys page? There seems to be no options to do that.